# Codeigniter - Passing query results to private function and back

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am running a query that returns 116 results.  I am then attempting to loop those results through another query and display the results in a table. I just can't seem to get them all in the same table.

```
function average_battery_life_by_truck() {

    $truck_num = $this->mhedash_model->select_truck();
    $result = $truck_num->result_array();


    foreach($result as $row){
    $data = $this->_average_truck($row['truck_num']);
        }
}

function _average_truck($array) {
    $data[] = $array;

    $query = $this->mhedash_model->select_battery_life_truck($array);
    $result1 =& $query->result_array();

    $this->table->set_heading('Average','Truck');
    $data['table'] = $this->table->generate_table($result1);

    $data['array2'] = $result1;

    $data['main_content'] = 'mhe/average_truck_bat';
    return $this->load->view('includes/template',$data);



}
```

//////
VIEW

```
<?php foreach($array2 as $row): ?>

    <TR >
        <TD><?php echo $row['average_bat_life']; ?></TD>
        <TD><?php echo $row['truck_num']; ?></TD>

    </TR>
    <?php $count++; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

This code will only give you the last result processed in the loop in `$data` as you are over writing it each time

```
foreach($result as $row){
    $data = $this->_average_truck($row['truck_num']);
}
```

Do this instead and you will get an array of results

```
foreach($result as $row){
    $data[] = $this->_average_truck($row['truck_num']);
}
```

Comment: I made the change and it displays all of the results in their own individual tables now, not in one collective table. I'm not sure if I'm looping it through wrong or what really.

Comment: From the code you shared it is not possible to comment on this next issue. You should really ask another question with this problem, and this time provided enough code for us to see the complete flow of your script

Comment: Thanks for all the help